# Error in passing file location in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a media Player in Java.
In order to do that, I'm passing a string where my file is located but I am getting an error.

Operating System: MacOSX
IDE: Pycharm

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    String file="~/Users/ViditShah/IdeaProjects/MediaPlayer/src/sample/1.mp4";
    Player player = new Player(file);
    Scene scene = new Scene(player,720,480, Color.BLACK);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Player Class:

```
public class Player extends BorderPane {
    Media media;
    MediaPlayer player;
    MediaView  view;
    Pane apane;
    Player(String file)
    {
        media =new Media(file);
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        view = new MediaView(player);

        apane.getChildren().add(view);

        setCenter(apane);
    }
}
```

The error is being shown in parsing the file String.
I guess I have made a mistake in locating my file path and failing to find solution.

Comment: You have a folder in your home directory called `Users`? That seems unlikely. I don't know what `Player` is, and without knowing that, it's not possible to really answer the question, but most methods in JavaFX that expect some kind of resource expect to be passed a URL (or a string form of a URL), not a file path.

Comment: ~ is shell not Java. You have to use full path or getenv $HOME. Alternatively, you can use "user.home" property.

Comment: @James_D I have Added Player Class code and have a copy of media file on Desktop as well.
I need path to feed in the String

Comment: that path with never work, Java has no idea what `~` is.

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html): "The Media class represents a media resource. It is instantiated from the string form of a source URI." So you should not be passing in a file path at all here. It looks like the mp4 is part of your actual project (not something on the user's file system) - so once your application is deployed it won't be a file at all, it will be bundled in the jar file containing the application. Is the class containing the code you posted in the same package as the mp4?

Comment: @James_D Considering the media file exists on my Desktop is there way to send that path to String ?

Comment: Well, sure, create a `File` object with the appropriate path and call `toURI().toString()`: but I don't think it makes any sense to do that. How do you know the user will have that mp4 in that location when they run your application? What are you trying to actually do here? Are you playing a video that the user is providing in some way (e.g. they choose a video from their file system), or are you playing a video that is supposed to be part of the application?

Comment: @James_D just testing for learning

Comment: Learning how to do what? How to play a video that is part of the application, or learning how to play a video that the user provides at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are apparently trying to pass a filesystem path to the [`Media`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html) constructor. According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/Media.html#Media-java.lang.String-):

> The Media class represents a media resource. It is instantiated from the string form of a source URI.

and

> The source must represent a valid URI and is immutable. Only HTTP, FILE, and JAR URLs are supported. If the provided URL is invalid then an exception will be thrown.

So it makes no sense at all to pass a filesystem path to the `Media` constructor. You have to pass it the string form of a URI.

There are two different scenarios that are possible here (and for some reason, you refuse to clarify which you are trying to do). Either you are trying to play a video which is part of your application, in which case the video will be included in the jar file for your application when it is deployed, or you are trying to play a video provided by the user at runtime.

In the former case, you basically need to load the video from wherever the JVM is loading classes (whether it be the file system, typically during development, or from a jar file, typically once the application is deployed). To do this, you get the URI from the class loader.

If the video is in the same package as the current class, you can do:

```
String videoURI = getClass().getResource("1.mp4").toURI().toString();
```

and pass that (via your `Player` constructor) to the `Media` constructor.

Or more generally, you can start the resource name with a `/`, in which case it will be searched relative to the classpath:

```
String videoURI = getClass().getResource("/sample/1.mp4").toURI().toString();
```

On the other hand, if you are playing a video that the user provides, you can create a URI from a `File` object:

```
File file = ... ;
String videoURI = file.toURI().toString();
```

For example, you might do:

```
FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("mp4 video files", "*.mp4"));
File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
if (file != null) {
    String videoURI = file.toURI().toString();
    // ...
}
```